# Stream attached to a string within program's memory

Tags: c++, io

In C++ Primer I came across a statement in `string stream`:

> The `iostream` library supports in-memory input/output, in which a stream is attached to a `string` within program's memory. That `string` can be written to and from using `iostream` input and output operators.

When in *nix system we input as `./a.out<file` then is the content of this file entered INTO the `stream` attached to a `string` within program's memory? or is it counted as file I/O?

Answer (score 0):

It does not have anything to do with stringstreams. *nix shell input redirection is explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/883822. Basically, the program (a.out in your case) does not care whether the shell is feeding the standard input or the keyboard input into the terminal is.